# Why use an Observable over HTTP in Angular

Tags: angular, http, observable

I'm new to Angular and i'm trying to figure out in what cases it's best to user rxjs/Observables vs just use the Http get/post calls.

From what I have read, Observables are best used when data needs to be loaded lazily in a push fashion rather than a pull fashion in Javascript. Also, it seems like the data will come in any number of batches which is not predefined. The only thing I can think of as a use case for Observables is to use web sockets and stuff like news feeds or something like a facebook feed kind of a scenario but I have seen some examples where Observables have been used to make an HTTP GET call as well. I am not sure why that's needed.

If I can just do a http.get, why do I need to do a http.get().subscribe?

Comment: observables and http get post are 2 different things. you are using get/post to get data from internet and observables are a paradigm of programming. if you are new to software development I would encourage you to read some basic fundamentals about reactive programming and then start angular. its tough at start but easy later on

Comment: https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-creating-and-subscribing-to-observables-in-angular-426dbf0b04a3 please check this out

Comment: http.get return an **Observable**, as all observables, you need subscribe to be executed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question *"Why use an Observable over HTTP"* relies on the false presumption that they are alternative ways to do the same thing. It's apples and oranges; Observables offer a way (a tool) to make and handle HTTP operations. It's kind of like asking *"Why use a fork over a bowl of rice?"*  The fork is just a tool to help handle the rice; they are not either/or options.

I will assume that the greater question is something like:

> "What good are Observable streams when in HTTP calls, all I need is to get my data one time right when I ask for it?"

This is a more interesting question.  It is true that in most simple cases, a basic Promise based approach like the native [`fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is sufficient, but it has its shortcomings.  The biggest advantages of Observables I can think of right now are:

- Observables are easier to compose and meld into existing logic flows: Suppose my application needs to react intelligently to the result of the initial HTTP call; for instance I may want to dynamically make another call, or skip that 2nd call given certain conditions, or to retry the original call after a delay, etc... These things would take more complexity and more code to make work with promises. Observables were built with logic streams in mind.
- Observables are a better fit when you care about more than just the final result: Suppose my application needs to give user feedback as a file is being uploaded or downloaded.  A Promise based approach won't work as well because a Promise resolves once, whereas an Observable stream can emit progress events.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Angular HttpClient service and you will be using a http client built with RxJs observables.

You can inject it into your services

```
constructor(http: HttpClient)
```

and use it like

```
this.http.get('URL to your endpoint');
```

You need to subscribe to fire the http request. Creating a cold observable doesn't have any data flowing until an observer subscribes to the observable.

Learn as much as you can about RxJs when starting Angular, Angular is heavily built with RxJs and you should learn RxJs before learning Angular.